# How to generate token to access Google apis using GCP service account

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, .net-core

I'm trying to generate access token to access google APIs without the google consent screen. It will enable us to implement code which can automate certain actions in GCP like stopping a VM and lots more. I prefer to use dotnet core for this implementation.

I except to generate a bearer auth token through which I can access Google rest APIs without any environment setup or Google OAuth consent screen.

Answer (score 1):

I have found answer for this question and it will be useful for the community members who are working on GCP or google APIs.
First you have to download json credentials for your gcp account, please refer to this documentation [Download service account keys](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys)

Please refer to this git repo [gcp-auth](https://github.com/b17saurabh/gcp-auth/) , it's dotnet core class library which contains static method to GenerateJwt, ExchangeTokenAsync and GetAccessTokenAsync.
Let me explain each method for better clarity.

**GenerateJwt** - this method generates a signed JWT token from PrivateKey, PrivateKeyID, ServiceAccountEmail which are present in downloaded json from previous step and scope which will be different for different api endpoint like we have `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute` for google apis under compute.

**ExchangeTokenAsync** - this method need the generated JWT from previous step to generate the actual access token from google which will be valid to access google apis under that scope.

**GetAccessTokenAsync** - this is combination of above two methods, here you've pass parameters same as passed in GenerateJwt.

Please let me know if it requires any further explanation.

Comment: From where do you generate this token? A service on Google Cloud? on your computer?

Comment: I generate JWT locally from my computer and exchange it with google access token using Google auth service.

Comment: Prefer not to use service account key file, it's more secure. Your own credentials are better to use ;)

Comment: I agree on that.